How can i get all the active users from a XMPP server(ejabberd) in C#?
i'm making a platform using c# for a project. I m using as nuGetPackage MatriX for connecting with the server. I need too extract a list of the all active users on the server, how can i do that?
I need a list of the active users.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
